# I don't know how to import packages from gradle dependancy

Tags: java, maven, gradle

So i am using gradle to get dependencies from maven central which is working fine. I just don't know how to import them to my actual java file.

How do i found out the name to import it?

at the top of my java file i have to write

```
import <name>
```

How do i find the name?

Thank You.

Comment: What do you mean as import? Import classes in java sources? Or some jar import into final archive?

Comment: as in import the library so i can use it. Very simple question. I have no idea what you mean by jar import into final archive. Just want to be able to use the damn dependency i downloaded with gradle!

Comment: I mean, you may want to get a so-called fatJar. Just to note, how did you found the library, you want to set as dependency and don't know the classes you want to import? If so, you might have to read javadocs for that lib

Comment: I found the library using maven central. I got the artifact id and group id, but i have already tried using the artifact id and group id to import it and they both don't work. I want to import everything from the dependency ~ .*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your comments. You have to import the packages, which are contained within the library, not the library itself. There is no guarantee, this package names are the same as group or artifact id of the library. To get know that package names, usually you may use a javadocs for the library. Or just simply let your IDE to make it for you, them you're trying to use some classes from that lib.

Alternatively, you can use some off-sites, like [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/), where you may find your library and take a look at the packages list within it. For example, description for [Apache Commons Lang](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.4) library, where you can see the "Packages" section with all the packages within the lib. You may import them, just like:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.*;
```

One more solution, is to unzip a jar and take a look into it's content to determine the packages structure.